# n this problem, you have to modify an existing C# program that reads in some product data,

Tags: c#-4.0

### Heading ##n this problem, you have to modify an existing C# program that reads in some product data, and does some processing on it.  A company has a number of products that they sell to customers, and each product uses one or more internal libraries. All internal libraries are given version numbers like v1, v2, v3, ... etc. which are incremented each time the internal library team releases a new version of the library to the product teams.  Consider input data (on stdin) which contains information about which versions of the various libraries are being used by the current release of each product of the company:  Mail Server, Authentication Library, v6 Video Call Server, Authentication Library, v7 Mail Server, Data Storage Library, v10 Chat Server, Data Storage Library, v11 Mail Server, Search Library, v6 Chat Server, Authentication Library, v8 Chat Server, Presence Library, v2 Video Call Server, Data Storage Library, v11 Video Call Server, Video Compression Library, v3 Each line of the input consists of 3 comma-separated fields. The first field is a product name, the second field is a library name, and the third field is the library version number used by that product. The example given above indicates that the Mail Server, uses version v6 of the Authentication Library, and the Video Call Server uses version v7 of the Authentication Library, and the Mail Server also uses version v10 of the Data Storage Library, and so on. For the purposes of this program, assume that all version numbers are of the form v where  represents one or more decimal digits.  The processData method does nothing - it just returns an empty list. Modify it so that, it processes the input data, figures out which is the latest version number of each library, and then prints the names of products which are using an outdated version (i.e. a version that is not the latest version) of at least one library, to standard output (console).  Thus, in case of the example input given above, the output of your program should be:  Mail Server Video

Comment: This is problem i need to complete today

Comment: Is this for a school assignment? Good luck!

Comment: yes  bro , please help me on this

Comment: is there a part of the assignment you don't understand? what have you done so far?

Comment: dont help leave it

Answer (score 1):

namespace OOPs
{

```
public class ProductInfo
{
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public string LibraryName { get; set; }
    public string Version { get; set; }
}

public class Program2
{
    public static List<String> processData( IEnumerable<string> lines)
    {
        var productInfoList = new List<ProductInfo>();

        foreach(var item in lines)
        {
            ProductInfo details = new ProductInfo();
            var split = item.Split(',');
            details.ProductName = split[0];
            details.LibraryName = split[1];
            details.Version = split[2];
            productInfoList.Add(details);
        }

        var versionMaxList = productInfoList.GroupBy(g => new {  g.LibraryName }).Select( x => new { maxVersion= x.Max( g=>g.Version ) , LibName =  x.Key.LibraryName } ) ;

        var list = from pdl in productInfoList
                   join vl in versionMaxList
                   on pdl.LibraryName equals vl.LibName
                   where pdl.Version != vl.maxVersion
                   select  new {   pdl.LibraryName, pdl.Version , pdl .ProductName};

        List<String> retVal = new List<String>();

        foreach(var item in list)
        {
            if(!retVal.Contains (item.ProductName))
            {
                retVal.Add(item.ProductName);
            }
        }
        return retVal;
    }

    public void MainMethod()
    {
        try
        {
            var inputLines = new List<String>();
            inputLines.Add("Mail Server, Authentication Library, v6");
            inputLines.Add("Video Call Server, Authentication Library, v7");
            inputLines.Add("Mail Server, Data Storage Library, v10"); //print 
            inputLines.Add("Chat Server, Data Storage Library, v11");
            inputLines.Add("Mail Server, Search Library, v7");
            inputLines.Add("Mail Server, Search Library, v6");
            inputLines.Add("Chat Server, Authentication Library, v8");
            inputLines.Add("Chat Server, Presence Library, v2");
            inputLines.Add("Video Call Server, Data Storage Library, v11");
            inputLines.Add("Video Call Server, Video Compression Library, v3");

            var retVal = processData(inputLines);
            foreach(var res in retVal)
                Console.WriteLine(res);
        }
        catch(IOException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }

}
```

}

Comment: to work this code we have to use equal(where pdl.Version == vl.maxVersion) instead of not equal(where pdl.Version != vl.maxVersion)

Answer (score 0):

Alternative to using LINQ: Use a dictionary!

```
public static List<String> processData(
                                    IEnumerable<string> lines)
    {
        
        // Declaring two lists: one for the final output, and one for interim processing
        List<String> retVal = new List<String>();
        List<String> interimVal = new List<String>();
        
        // Declaring two dictionaries, one for storing the entries, and one for the max library versions
        // The entries will have to be compared against the library versions
        Dictionary<string, int> libraries = new Dictionary<string, int>();
        Dictionary<string, int> entries = new Dictionary<string, int>();
        
        // Iterating over each of the input lines
        foreach (var line in lines)
        {
            var splitData = line.Split(',');
            
            // Adding the line to the entries dictionary. This will later be compared
            // String operation for the value, to remove the 'v'. Alternative: Substring from position '1'
            entries.Add(splitData[0] + " " + splitData[1], Int32.Parse(splitData[2].ToString().Replace('v',' ')));
            
            // Check if the libraries dictionary contains the element. If it doesn't, add it
            // If the element exists, then check the version value. Update it to max value.
            if (!libraries.ContainsKey(splitData[1]))
            {
                libraries.Add(splitData[1], Int32.Parse(splitData[2].ToString().Replace('v',' ')) );
            }
            else
            {
                if (libraries[splitData[1]] < Int32.Parse(splitData[2].ToString().Replace('v',' ')) )
                {
                    libraries[splitData[1]] = Int32.Parse(splitData[2].ToString().Replace('v',' ')) ;
                }
            }
        }
        
        // Comparing the key value pairs for entries and libraries
        // If version info doesn't match with the max, we'll add it to the interim output List
        // Interim specified because distinct Products are needed in the final output
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> entry in entries)
        {
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> library in libraries)
            {
                if (entry.Key.Contains(library.Key) && entry.Value < library.Value)
                {
                    var splitOutput = entry.Key.Split(" ");
                    if (!interimVal.Contains(splitOutput[0] + " " + splitOutput[1]))
                    {
                        interimVal.Add(splitOutput[0] + " " + splitOutput[1]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        
        // Final step: Add the word 'Server' in case it isn't there.
        foreach (var val in interimVal)
        {
            if (!val.Contains("Server"))
            {
                retVal.Add(val + " Server");
            }
            else
            {
                retVal.Add(val);
            }
        }
        
        retVal.Sort();
        return retVal;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I came across a different variant of a similar problem yesterday. My problem statement says I have to find all the products which have at least one latest version of the API, then show them in descending order based on the count of all the latest version of API's the product has. For Ex:

```
Mail Server, Authentication Library, v6
Video Call Server, Authentication Library, v7
Mail Server, Data Storage Library, v10
Chat Server, Data Storage Library, v11
Mail Server, Search Library, v6
Chat Server, Authentication Library, v8
Chat Server, Search Library, v7
Video Call Server, Data Storage Library, v10
Video Call Server, Video Compression Library, v3
```

For the above list, the output should be:
*Chat Server, Video Call Server*

Chat Server has three latest API's: Data Storage Library, Authentication Library, Search Library.
Video Call Server: Video Compression Library

Mail Server is not included because it doesn't have any latest version of the API's.

```
public static void findProductsWithAtleastOneLatestAPI(ArrayList<String> array) {

    Map<String, Integer> api = new HashMap<String, Integer>(); // Getting used for storing all the API's and its
                                                                // latest version
    HashMap<String, Integer> products = new HashMap<String, Integer>(); // Map for storing all the products and
                                                                        // count of latest API's it has

    List<String> output = new ArrayList<String>();

    // This loop is traversing over the list, to find the latest version of every
    // API and storing it in API Map, also it is getting used to store all the
    // products name in products map
    for (int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++) {

        String str = array.get(i);
        String[] s1 = str.split(",");

        String s1_index0 = s1[0].trim();
        String s1_index1 = s1[1].trim();
        String s1_index2 = s1[2].trim();

        int version = Integer.parseInt(s1_index2.substring(1, s1_index2.length()));
        if (api.containsKey(s1_index1)) {
            int temp = api.get(s1_index1);
            if (version > temp)
                api.put(s1_index1, version);
        } else
            api.put(s1_index1, version);

        products.put(s1_index0, 0);
    }

    // In this we are again traversing over the list to check the current version of
    // the API with the latest version from the API map, if it matches then increase
    // the count of product map
    for (int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++) {
        String str = array.get(i);
        String[] s1 = str.split(",");

        String s1_index0 = s1[0].trim();
        String s1_index1 = s1[1].trim();
        String s1_index2 = s1[2].trim();

        int version = Integer.parseInt(s1_index2.substring(1, s1_index2.length()));

        int temp = api.get(s1_index1);
        if (version == temp) {
            int current = products.get(s1_index0);
            products.put(s1_index0, ++current);
        }
    }

    // Sort map based on values in descending order and add it to list which has
    // values greater than 0
    Map<String, Integer> result = products.entrySet().stream()
            .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByValue(Comparator.reverseOrder())).collect(Collectors.toMap(
                    Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue, (oldValue, newValue) -> oldValue, LinkedHashMap::new));

    for (String key : result.keySet()) {
        if (products.get(key) > 0)
            output.add(key);
    }
    System.out.println(output);
}
```

I didn't found any code related to Java regarding this question so thought of posting it here. Hope this will work for people who are looking for Java solution.